# How to protect the camera in my new Lumia 950?

Tags: camera

I've just upgraded my old ATIV S for a new 950.

I've never used a case/cover/protector in any previous phone as I don't want any extra bulk in the pocket. And I don't care about the screen or body. My old ATIV is cracked, chipped and dented and i really don't care. Works fine in every respect bar the camera which takes blurred photos presumably due to scratched/worn camera lens.

So in the new Lumia I would like to protect the camera lens from wear.

So how to protect the camera lens? Looking at cases/covers online they just seem to have a cut out for the camera and seem more about protecting the body/screen.

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple silicone case for my Lumia 930 and the cutout for the camera actually protects the camera quite well because it prevents it from directly touching surfaces which usually causes scratches. I've had it for almost a year now and there's no visible damage on it at all. Apart from the occasional dust or fingerprints which can just be wiped off. So a slim case for your 950 is probably the easiest way to go.